# How to show quill data on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flutter, quill

I used the quill-delta-to-html package and managed to display the text on the screen. However, the styles were not displayed properly.

```
const deltaOps = blog.content2
const cfg = {};
const converter = new QuillDeltaToHtmlConverter(deltaOps, cfg);
const html = converter.convert();
```

So, GPT suggested something to me. Here's the suggestion:

```
const cfg = {
inlineStyles: {
  bold: 'font-weight: bold;',
  italic: 'font-style: italic;',
  underline: 'text-decoration: underline;',
  strike: 'text-decoration: line-through;',
  script: (value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 'sub':
        return 'vertical-align: sub;';
      case 'super':
        return 'vertical-align: super;';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  },
  background: (value) => {
    return `background-color: ${value};`;
  },
  color: (value) => {
    return `color: ${value};`;
  },
  font: (value) => {
    return `font-family: ${value};`;
  },
  size: (value) => {
    return `font-size: ${value}px;`;
  }
}
```

But this also didn't work.

Comment: quill/quill-delta-to-html

Comment: No worries, should be enough information with those terms to find what you need. :)

Comment: The contents inside the "attributes" are not visible on the screen.